# How to automate test cases having multiple scenarios within each test case using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am stuck in a situation where I am trying to automate the multiple test cases having multiple scenarios within each test case. I tried using for loop, while loop, do while loop but no success. 
My utilizing specifications are as follows:

Tool: Selenium WebDriver 2, 
Language:Java.

In other words I am trying to automate the following functionality which is the perfect replica of my need in real world; I would appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

Thanks

Here is what I am talking about:
[image: Here is the snapshot of the test case structure]

Comment: Why are you testing math? I think we've got it right by now.

Comment: And most of your expected results are wrong.

Comment: @Zymus, I am testing math because I am perusing big inventions based on these simple math calculations. Eventually you will also get there one day like others.

Comment: AND @chrylis, most of my expected results are wrong because of some logic behind it.

Comment: @TJDardi Bit presumptuous to think that. What I was trying to indicate was that these tests would provide no value. By testing `1+1=2` you're not testing your code, you're testing the compiler/runtime.

Comment: @Zymus; Bit presumptuousness was based on the quite presumptuous activity. This basic mathematical calculation represents the exact replica of my complex application and I want to parameterize it with the best options out there.

Comment: @Zymus If you're using Selenium, you are likely to be testing *the UI*, making sure the inputs are wired in correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka !! I figured this out. It was so simple that I can't even believe that I was stuck on such a quiet simple logic. All you have to do is to use a for loop in the main for loop and for that you have to declare a lot of variables. I know it's not a good practice but a good practice to learn for sure.

Thanks everybody for looking at one of my issues and shout out to the people who tried to solve my problem.

Thanks,
TJ

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're wanting a parameterized test. All of the standard test frameworks (including JUnit and TestNG) have support for parameterized tests, and Spock, which also integrates very well with Geb, [makes them particularly easy](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html). If you were using Geb, your test might look something like this (presuming you're testing a JavaScript-based single-page calculator):

```
@Unroll // lists each combination separately in test results
def "#num1 #operator #num2 == #expected"(int num1, String operator, int num2, int expected) {
    when:
        to CalculatorPage
        form.num1 = num1
        form.num2 = num2
        form.operatorButton(operator).click()

    then:
        expected == output as int

    where:
        num1 | operator | num2 || expected
        6    | '+'      | 6    || 12
        8    | '/'      | 2    || 1
        9    | '*'      | 5    || 45
}
```

Comment: Hey @chrylis, thanks for helping me. Any example with TestNG or JUnit will be great as I am not familiar with Geb yet.

Comment: @TJDardi For Selenium testing, learning Geb usually pays back immediately because of how simple the expressions are.

Comment: @chrylis: Thanks a lot. I will definitely give it a shot.